# R barplot using Hive table

Tags: r, hive

Am completely new to R and am facing this problem:

My R variable **sales** has these values which I got by running a select query on a **hive** table

```
sales
       X_c0 sales
1 316650838    3G
2 133072300    TT
```

am trying to plot a bar graph using R with 3G and TT on X axis and their values on Y axis. How can I do this?
I tried **barplot(sales)** but it gives an error saying **height needs to vector or matrix.**

Comment: check [Bar Charts in R](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/) or [Bar Plots](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use `?` : `?barplot`

And here's how you can do it:

```
barplot(df$X_c0,names.arg = df$sales)
```

data :

```
df <- read.table(text="       X_c0 sales
1 316650838    3G
2 133072300    TT",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.